# Elasticsearch get data using search in PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to get data from elastic search in PHP. 
Following is my elastic type (curated) structure :

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "qwerty",
        "_type": "curated",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "shows_on_lfz": [
            {
              "sh_id": 14,
              "sh_parent_id": 102,
              "sh_name": "Veg Versions Of Global Dishes"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "qwerty",
        "_type": "curated",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "top_stories": [
            {
              "ts_id": 515,
              "ts_parent_id": 485,
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I get all data of `top_stories` using search query in PHP?
I am getting data using `match_all` & `get()` query but I need data using `search()`.

I tried - 
`$body['query']['bool']['should'] = ['match' => ['top_stories'=> '']];`

But getting a null response.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query that will bring all entries that have the field `top_stories`

```
GET qwerty/_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "top_stories"
    }
  }
}
```

You can convert this to code and you can test it through kibana